Solve a nonlinear SDE with hint.
Given $W_t$ is a standard Wiener process, solve $$dX_t=X_tdt+X_t^2dW_t$$
Hint: use the transformation $f(t,X_t)=1/X_0-1/X_t$.
The following is what I tried: by Ito's formula,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
df(t,X_t)&=\partial_xfdX_t+\frac{1}{2}\partial_{xx}f dX_t\cdot dX_t \\
&=\frac{1}{X_t^2}(X_tdt+X_t^2dW_t)-\frac{1}{X_t^3}X_t^4dt \\
&= (\frac{1}{X_t}-X_t)dt+dW_t
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Then what I have no idea how to proceed from here. I don't see why the hint is helpful here. Or there is another way to utilize the hint?
Any idea is appreciated!
